# RACObserve bounds or frame of a UIView?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I create a signal to observe the width of a text field's frame in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
RACSignal *destinationDisplayWidthSignal =
    [RACObserve(self.destinationNumberTextField, frame)
        map:^id(NSValue *value) {
            NSLog(@"rect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([value CGRectValue]));
            return @(CGRectGetWidth([value CGRectValue]));
        }];
```

However, the signal did not send the **next** event after the frame changes in `-viewDidAppear:`. I try to replace `frame` with `bounds` and it works!

Should I always observe the `bounds` of a UIView using `RACObserve()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no one answer, some code will call `-setFrame:`, while other code will call `-setBounds:`. If the code that sets the rect is not your code, then you could observe both `bounds` and `frame` and merge the two signals. For example:

```
[[[RACSignal
    merge:@[RACObserve(view, frame), RACObserve(view, bounds)]]
    logNext]
    map:^(NSValue *value) {
        return @(CGRectGetWidth([value CGRectValue]));
    }]
```